# cd to user defined path

Tags: python, cmd

I was wondering if you could help me with my new python program. I recently added a browse button to the GUI to make things more "user-friendly." I told python to only accept *.pvt files when the user is asked to browse for a file... Now, I am left wondering how to tell python to take the path the user browsed to and open a cmd window[using subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe")] and cd to that user defined path.. any ideas???

here's what i have so far...

```
 def OnAbout3(self, event):
           """
           Browse for file
           """
           wildcard = "Select File (*.pvt)|*.pvt"
           dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file",
                                  wildcard=wildcard,
                                  style=wx.OPEN)
           if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
              path = dialog.GetPaths()
              #######this is where i wanted to do something like this:
              subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe")
              #I wished cmd could simply cd to the variable, path
              os.system('cd path')
              dialog.Destroy()
```

so, obviously, this doesn't cd to path. how can i do this??

Comment: How about `cmd.exe /k cd path`?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this:

```
subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', cwd=path)
```

This is based on the assumption, that you don't really want to `cd`, but instead want the current working directory to be set - which is the post condition of `cd`...

Check the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) for more awesome parameters and examples!

Comment: it didn't work.. i got an error using this code.. "must be string, not list."

Comment: @user715578: use `dialog.GetPath()`, not `.GetPaths()`. You're not allowing multiple selections anyway, and you want 1 path, not a list of files.

Comment: it says directory name is invalid.. :(

Comment: could you print the directory name to the console before starting `cmd.exe`? let's show some of your debugging skillz here!

Comment: I'm sorry.... I just started python not too long ago and I am lost.. how would I go about doing so?

Comment: @user715578: just add a line `print path` just after assignment and check the output. Do lots of prints while writing the code and then remove these statements afterwards. This will help you see what is going on in your program.